# Query regarding ConcurrentHashMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency

I have a query regarding `ConcurrentHashMap`.

`ConcurrentHashMap` is a map for concurrent access. `ConcurrentHashMap` implements `ConcurrentMap` which extends `Map`.

a) `ConcurrentHashMap` implements the methods defined in `ConcurrentMap` (like `putifAbsen`t etc) which are atomic.

b) But, how about the methods in the Map interface which `ConcurrentMap` extends?
   How are they now atomic? Have they been reimplemented by `ConcurrentHashMap`

If I have a reference of type `ConcurrentHashMap` and call a method from 
   the `Map` Interface(e.g put) or any other method, is that method an atomic method?

Comment: What did you see by looking at the code?  Does it look like a copy or a re-implementation?

Answer (score 1):

`Map` is just an interface. Therefore the `ConcurrentHashMap` has an atomic implementation of those methods.

The `putIfAbsent` method is a convenient way in a concurrent environment to execute an atomic `if not contains then put` that you cannot do from the `Map` interface even though the `Map` is actually of type `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentHashMap does not extend HashMap. They are both implementations of a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), but ConcurrentHashMap has very different internals to HashMap in order to provide concurrency.

If you provide a ConcurrentHashMap to a method that accepts Map, then that will work, and you will get the concurrent behaviour you expect. Map is simply an interface that describes a set of methods, ConcurrentHashMap implements that interface with concurrent behaviour.

There is a difference between 'concurrent' and 'atomic'. Concurrent means that multiple operations can happen at the same time and the Map (or whatever data structure we are talking about) will ALWAYS BE IN A VALID STATE. This means that you can have multiple threads calling put(), get(), remove(), etc on this map and there will never be any errors (if you try this with a regular HashMap you WILL get errors as it isn't designed to handle concurrency).

Atomic means that an action that takes multiple steps appears to take a single step to other threads - as fair as they are aware it has completely finished or hasn't even started yet. For ConcurrentHashMap, putIfAbsent() is one such example. From the javadoc,

If the specified key is not already associated with a value, associate it with the given value. This is equivalent to:

```
if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
   return map.put(key, value);
else
   return map.get(key);
```

except that the action is performed atomically.

If you tried the above code with a ConcurrentHashMap, you wouldn't get any errors (since it is Concurrent), but there is a good change that other threads would interleave with the main thread and your entry would get overwritten or removed. ConcurrentMap specifies the atomic putIfAbsent() method to ensure that implementations can perform those steps atomically, without interference from other threads.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of these methods like put() and remove() are getting the lock on the final Sync object, concurrent retrieval will always give the most recent data on the map.

In case of putAll() or clear(), which operates on whole Map, concurrent read may reflect insertion and removal of only some entries.

Below Two links will help you to understand:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/02/concurrenthashmap-in-java-example-tutorial-working.html

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_8_hashmap2.shtml

Comment: This completely depends on the implementation. What you say is true for HashMap (although memory visibility is the least of your problems, you will get errors), but not for ConcurrentHashMap, where all changes are visible to other threads immediately.

Comment: @TomMcIntyre: May be I am Not clear, but from the documention it clearly says the statment " putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries". http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html. It will be great if you are helping me understand little further.

Comment: My comment was aimed more at your first paragraph. If a thread returns from calling put() on a ConcurrentHashMap, all other threads will be able to see the result of that operation, no further synchronization is required.

Comment: @TomMcIntyre: Thnks for the clarification. Corrected my response.